# Where should I ask a question about a program that wants to connect to the Internet

Tags: support, asking-questions

I have a program that is limiting other programs to access the Internet, and I want to ask about some programs that want to connect, what purpose this connection is for. e.g. Chrome tool wants to connect to port 443 somewhere - what is this for?

I thought this kind of suits [Super User](https://superuser.com/) but the faq says it's not about web-services so I'm having trouble deciding.

Comment: @gnat is Internet really a name?

Comment: @Martin see Wikipedia article about [Internet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question would fit perfectly on [Super User](http://superuser.com).

The [Super User FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) **does** say that it's not about web services, but in this case, your question is about programs that connect to the internet, which falls in one of the two on topic categories: software.

Examples:

- Why can't I log into my GMail account is a question for [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com), since the problem is related to GMail (a web app).
- Why does my browser crash when trying to log into GMail is a question for [Super User](http://superuser.com), since it's related to your browser (computer software).

Answer (score -1):

As far as it's a practical programming question, aim it to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

In your case, it's more about applications. If it's a web application, choose [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/) otherwise

Comment: That's not a programming question

Comment: Whoops, I think I haven't read the question properly

Comment: +1  I thought about programmers(http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) too but in the end of the day, after reading both of their faq's, SO (http://stackoverflow.com/faq) probably fits best